# Drop-down list in hybrid app has black text on grey backround on certain android devices

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

We have a hybrid app built with phonegap and jquery mobile. 
In one screen we have standard HTML5 select (drop-down list)

On one android device, Samsung S6 Galaxy with Android System WebView M42, the drop-down is shown with black text on grey background. See screenshot.

On all other Android devices it is shown with white text on grey background.

Are there any way of fixing this from the hybrid app?

[image: Drop-down list on Samsung S6 Galaxy]

Comment: if You set the background and textColor as attribute, it should not happen...

Comment: This is a <select> element and the drop-down list is therefore a native component. But it could be that S6 uses the css color of the select in the text. Changing it to white just in case

Comment: @dparnas did you managed to fix it?

Comment: @yuri nope, unfortunately not

Comment: Same issue on Samsung Galaxy A5

Comment: I have a feeling this can be fixed with custom theme. Currently I am using
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal fix, but i fixed it by switching to older android theme. In your manifest file

`android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We´re using phonegap build for building the app (not the cordova client) so we cant update directly in the cordova generated code.

Comment: @dparnas i am using phonegap myself. You can still go to AndroidManifest.xml in your platforms folder and add it there as an attribute to `<application>` element

EDIT: Ah sorry, just realised that you are using "phonegap build web service"

Answer (score 0):

Have you reduced this to the simplest of examples?  Just use the default app template, add in jquery mobile and create a list and show it to make sure it really is a problem specific to that device / environment.

The reason I ask is that I ran into similar issues until I ran my app's html and css through the WC3 validators.  Turns out there were a couple misplaced tags here and there that caused issues only in some environments.

Comment: That's nothing to do with css, it's a native Android dropdown. I fixed it by switching to Holo.Light theme for now `android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"`